# How to declare CHECK constraint with Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, check-constraints

How is it possible to know, which data annotations are supported by `Spring JPA`?

For example, is [`@Min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html) supported?

```
   @Min(value = 0)
   private double calories;
```

Anyway, how can one declare `CHECK` constraint?

**UPDATE**

Please read about [CHECK constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_constraint). Also note, that [`@Min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html) is a hyperlink.

Comment: "Spring JPA" does nothing other than provide a layer over the JPA API. JPA API provides nothing explicitly for adding a CHECK constraint in the datastore but allows you to specify columnDetails. Look at the javadocs

Comment: Thanks. But how to know that `javax.validation.constraints.Min` is not supported?

Comment: Apart from the question. This is not related to Spring JPA nor JPA itself. This is called Bean Validation (formerly known as JSR 303. Hibernate Validator is a reference implementation of JSR 303. It is JSR 349, since Bean Validation 1.1).

Comment: So, please someone answer that no annotation for `CHECK` constraint exist and that the only way is `columnDetails` option. Also I would like downvotes removed, because question is absolutely normal.

Comment: You can always create a custom validation constraint of your own doing the same as `CHECK` in the underlying database.

Comment: "is not supported" ? by what ? any jpa provider will enable a hook for such bean-validation annotations.

Comment: @Tiny so as with `UNIQUE` constraint. Nevertheless, an annotation exist for this.

Comment: It is very unlikely but I don't know as I am currently not actively concerned with Hibernate Validator.

Answer (score 10):

About validations executed by `javax.validation` API I don't know. But you can declare a constraint using `@javax.persistence.Column` annotation. For example, to create a check constraint to force accept only some values to a `VARCHAR` column you coul use the following code:

```java
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(60) CHECK (status IN ('ACTIVE', 'PENDING', 'INACTIVE')))
private String status;
```

Comment: I agree. `javax.validation` API is the best to validate values

Comment: Does this change the table definition or does it just check in the java side before performing `save()`? I would rather not touch the table definition

Comment: Unless you explicitly tell your JPA provider to update or generate the schema from the annotations, this is purely documentation. And the Bean Validation will not use this annotation to check anything, those are separate annotations.